# How to get total number of edits for a given wikipedia page from the API?

Tags: wikipedia-api

I actually do not want to list each edit, but to get only the count of it.

this data is available for every article on the left panel in link:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Wikipedia&action=info
```

But this produces complete web page with tables, formatting etc and its exhaustive for wikipedia servers. So I ask if is there a way to only get those few numbers and ommit the whole website scraping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not the answer you want but there isn't a way to get this information [yet.](http://wikimedia.7.x6.nabble.com/Getting-the-total-edits-on-an-article-from-the-API-td5013348.html)

As a workaround you can use the `prop=revisions` to get all the revisions contributed to the article. You will be able to count the `rev` tag from here:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=Wikipedia&prop=revisions&rvprop=ids&rvlimit=max
```

Alternatively, you can ask YQL to count it for you with the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM xml 
WHERE url="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=query&titles=Wikipedia&prop=revisions&rvprop=ids&rvlimit=max" 
AND itemPath="/api/query/pages/page/revisions/rev"
```

Example output [(Link to full output)](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=show%20tables&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=):

```
{
    "query": {
        "count": 500, //This is the total amount of edits
        "created": "2014-03-04T02:29:42Z",
        "lang": "en-US",
        "results": {
            "rev": [{
                "parentid": "597995345",
                "revid": "598005528"
            }, {
                "parentid": "597994174",
                "revid": "597995345"
            }, {
                "parentid": "597891867",
                "revid": "597994174"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the [upper limit](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aProperties#revisions_.2F_rv) for users to retrieve revision data is `500` and for bots it's `5000`.

To get the exact count, you will have to set up a parser on your server to capture the exact count from the info page whenever a user queries the data from your side.

Comment: The limit is there for a single request, you can get the total count using `query-continue` and multiple requests.